# Find and replace multiple words in HTML

Tags: html, jquery

I have multiple HTML files with numbered paragraphs. Without CSS, I'm looking for a way to add bold to the numbers.

I tried with jQuery adding this option:

```
$(document).html(html.replace("1", "<strong>1</strong>"))
```

but each file has 50 numbers. How can I do it for all of them?

The HTML file is like this:

```
<div id="content">1 Lorem ipsum pain sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse egestas tortor non elit finibus, nec iaculis nulla tempus. . <br />
2 Lorem ipsum pain sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse egestas tortor non elit finibus, nec iaculis nulla tempus. Duis hendrerit velit at mauris molestie, tempus tristique eros sollicitudin. . <br />
3 Lorem ipsum pain sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse egestas tortor non elit finibus, nec iaculis nulla tempus. Duis hendrerit velit at mauris molestie, tempus tristique eros sollicitudin. . <br />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `replaceAll()`.

`\d` searches for all digits, and `$&` is the match.

### jQuery

```js
$('#content').html($('#content').html().replaceAll(/\d/g, '<strong>$&</strong>'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">1 Lorem ipsum pain sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse egestas tortor non elit finibus, nec iaculis nulla tempus. . <br /> 2 Lorem ipsum pain sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse egestas tortor non elit finibus, nec iaculis
  nulla tempus. Duis hendrerit velit at mauris molestie, tempus tristique eros sollicitudin. . <br /> 3 Lorem ipsum pain sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse egestas tortor non elit finibus, nec iaculis nulla tempus. Duis hendrerit velit
  at mauris molestie, tempus tristique eros sollicitudin. . <br />
</div>
```

### Vanilla JS

```js
const content = document.getElementById('content');
content.innerHTML = content.innerHTML.replaceAll(/\d/g, '<strong>$&</strong>');
```

```html
<div id="content">1 Lorem ipsum pain sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse egestas tortor non elit finibus, nec iaculis nulla tempus. . <br /> 2 Lorem ipsum pain sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse egestas tortor non elit finibus, nec iaculis
  nulla tempus. Duis hendrerit velit at mauris molestie, tempus tristique eros sollicitudin. . <br /> 3 Lorem ipsum pain sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse egestas tortor non elit finibus, nec iaculis nulla tempus. Duis hendrerit velit
  at mauris molestie, tempus tristique eros sollicitudin. . <br />
</div>
```

---

Comment: also works very well

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions with `replace` to accomplish this, like the snippet below.

Quick breakdown of the `/([0-9])/g` query:

- The beginning and ending slashes without quotation marks indicate that we're using `replace` with a regex statement
- The `g` at the end means we're looking for the query globally instead of just once
- The parentheses indicates we're searching for regex groups, which allows us to include them in the replacement like `$1`, `$2`, etc (but we only need the first one since we have one group)
- We're looking for only numeric characters, `[0-9]`

```js
$('#content').html($('#content').html().replace(/([0-9])/g, "<strong>$1</strong>"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  1 Lorem ipsum pain sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse egestas tortor non elit finibus, nec iaculis nulla tempus. . <br /> 
  2 Lorem ipsum pain sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse egestas tortor non elit finibus, nec iaculis nulla tempus. Duis hendrerit velit at mauris molestie, tempus tristique eros sollicitudin. <br /> 
  3 Lorem ipsum pain sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse egestas tortor non elit finibus, nec iaculis nulla tempus. Duis hendrerit velit at mauris molestie, tempus tristique eros sollicitudin. <br /> 
  50 Lorem ipsum pain sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse egestas tortor non elit finibus, nec iaculis nulla tempus. Duis hendrerit velit at mauris molestie, tempus tristique eros sollicitudin.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the string replace using JavaScript

html content using del or ins elements

```
var str = "JavaScript replace method test";
var res = str.replace("test", "success");
```